# Vue.js how to use tabs to load different components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

I am trying to use a click event on my tabs to set the value of a variable inside `data()` I then use this variable in an if statement on my components to test the value and display the component if true. But this isn't working and I'm getting no errors. I assume that the value of the variable isn't being set when the click event on the tabs fires. Can I not achieve the functionality with this method?

```
<template>
    <div id="settings_page" class="page_body">
        <h1>Settings</h1>

        <div id="user_info" v-if="user">
            <div id="tabs">
                <div v-on:click="selected_tab == 'account'">Account Details</div>
                <div v-on:click="selected_tab == 'divisions'">Divisions</div>
                <div v-on:click="selected_tab == 'users'">Users</div>
                <div v-on:click="selected_tab == 'columns'">Columns</div>
            </div>

            <div class="content">
                <div v-if="selected_tab == 'account'">
                    <h2>Profile</h2>
                </div>

                <div v-if="selected_tab == 'divisions'">
                    divisions
                </div>

                <div v-if="selected_tab == 'users'">
                    users
                </div>

                <div v-if="selected_tab == 'columns'">
                    columns
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapActions, mapGetters } from 'vuex';

    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                selected_tab: 'account'
            }
        },
        computed:mapGetters(['user']),
        methods: {
            ...mapActions(['getProfile'])
        },
        created() {
            this.getProfile();
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: In your content div I would suggest putting a dynamic component with `<component :is=...` check documentation here : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're doing a comparison in the click event handler :

<del>`v-on:click="selected_tab == 'account'"`</del>

You should use assignment like :

`v-on:click="selected_tab = 'account'"`